# Extrude pattern from modeled mesh

Tags: modeling, modifiers, sculpting, extrude

I have been trying multiple methods to extrude motifs from a figure. The end result should look like raised skin off the model. I've tried modeling it on as well as using different modifiers but can't seem to figure it out, there are also not much tutorials on this specific method. I have both the figure and extruded SVG file in blender. Not sure if I actually need both. I'm fairly new to blender but would really like to figure this out.

[image]

Is there a way to mask the shape on the model and extrude? Or does it have to be fully sculpted? Or possibly a way to bend the solid SVG motifs against the line of the body?

Comment: If the relief is shallow, and never really seen as a raised profile, could this be a bump-map, rather than geometry? That would be a lot cheaper...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is there a way to mask the shape on the model and extrude?

Yes, to some degree. You can UV map the faces that you want to have the motif to the image of the motif. Then, using a Displace modifier, you can apply the displacement according to the UV map. You will need enough mesh resolution to see the pattern.

> Or does it have to be fully sculpted?

No, but if you want to sculpt it, it is definitely possible by using the image as a texture for the brush. You will still need enough mesh resolution to see the pattern. If you use Dyntopo, you may not need to subdivide the mesh beforehand.

> Or possibly a way to bend the solid SVG motifs against the line of the body?

If you want, you can do that with modifiers. You will need to convert the imported SVG curve to a mesh and model it into a 3D shape. Then, you will bind it to a subdivided plane using a Surface Deform modifier. Finally, using a Shrinkwrap modifier, you will project the plane to the model's surface. This option won't require a dense mesh as the motif geometry won't be connected to the character's mesh.

Please let me know if you want to know more about any of these approaches.

---

**Update:** The steps below cover the second approach. The motif needs to be a grayscale image where black represents no displacement and while represents full displacement. The image I used in my setup is attached below. It's 512 x 512. The resolution is not that important, but it should be square.

[image: Pattern]

1. Select the object and switch to Sculpt Mode.
2. Open the Texture panel, and click the *New* button to create a new texture.
3. While here, set the *Mapping* to *Area Plane*.

[image: 1]

4. Once a new texture is created, four buttons will appear. Click the last one on the right. This will open the Texture Properties.
5. Open the image by clicking the *Open* button and browsing to the image.

[image: 2]

6. Change the *Extension* under *Mapping* to *Clip*.
7. Enable Dyntopo by clicking the checkbox next to its button in the 3D Viewport.
8. Open the panel, and set the *Detail Size* to something around 4.00 px. You may need to decrease it further to get the resolution you need. The smaller it is the heavier it is to sculpt a motif, but the more resolution it will have.

[image: 3]

The setup is done now. You only need to click where you want the motif to show up. Please make sure not to click and drag. Also, don't forget to adjust the *Radius* and *Strength* of the brush.

The screenshot below show the settings I used and a sample achieve by clicking once with the brush. I marked the important settings.

[image: 4]

I attached one more screenshot that shows how a brush click modifies the geometry.

[image: 5]

Comment: Hi Mr A, thanks for your response. I think the last option with the modifiers seem the most doable for me. Do you happen to have suggestions on which tutorials I should use? It is a very thorough explanation already, but some more guidance would be helpful in achieving the result I'm looking for.

Comment: Your first suggestion seems the simplest, but I have no experience in UV mapping. Actually, which one would you suggest? I would also like to add that I have tried to use the shrink-wrap modifier on the flat SVG->mesh onto the model, but the result was incredibly flat and manipulated in an odd way.

Comment: If you're looking for the easiest, the second with Dyntopo is what I suggest. It may be a bit heavy considering how thin the motifs are. I will provide more details in my answer.

Comment: Thanks so much, will be anticipating. I don't have much experience in modeling either... but just looked up an introductory video and seems doable. Thanks for your suggestions, they helped a lot.

Comment: You're welcome. I added the steps to my answer.

Comment: "I would also like to add that I have tried to use the shrink-wrap modifier on the flat SVG->mesh onto the model, but the result was incredibly flat and manipulated in an odd way." That's expected as the Shrinkwrap will operate on all vertices. You can use a vertex group and some complicated setup to avoid this issue. However, the approach of using a Surface Deform modifier targeting a plane that is shrinkwrapped to the surface will work around this issue.

Comment: Ahh thank you for your step by step, it's very thorough I'm feeling confident. I have one last question, would you recommend I do each motif separately? My original file has them all placed together like so in the image attached.

Comment: You're welcome. You have to import each image separately and configure it as a texture for the brush. The best approach is probably to sculpt/stamp each motif separately, and then move on to the next. Some of the work doesn't have to be repeated, but importing the motifs in the 3D scene is not necessary.

Comment: Hi Mr. A, thanks so much for your help. It worked really well!!! And was extremely simple thanks to your helpful step by step images. I was wondering if you had any suggestions on how to make the edges appear smoother when the motif is stamped? I played with the pixel size and have the refine method set to subdivide edges, but was possibly there's a simpler method I'm missing?

Comment: You're welcome! I think the best way is to blur the texture a bit. White is full displacement; black is no displacement, so if you have a few pixels in the gray range, they will give a smoother falloff. Blurring the image can be quickly done in GIMP/Photoshop, but it can also be done in Blender in the Compositor. If you don't know how, let me know.